# Where can I get seamless 500dpi DRGs for Oahu (Honolulu County)?

Tags: raster, usgs, seamless

USGS makes 500dpi DRGs but doesn't seem to offer them for download anywhere. There are several vendors that I can find offering seamless DRGs but only in 250dpi. Where can I find 500dpi seamless DRGs for Oahu?

GeoPDFs will not work-- I have already tried importing them to Photoshop, exporting high res TIFFs, and georeferencing those, but I really need the edges to match perfectly.

Comment: If you have the data in GeoPDF format, GDAL supports it (http://www.gdal.org/frmt_pdf.html) and you can convert to GeoTIFF retaining the georeferencing metadata.

Comment: I think it's more time/cost effective to pay a few bucks for existing 500 DPI pdfs vs spending weeks or months learning how to compile and then use GDAL. I would still then need to figure out how to clip each DRG to remove everything outside the neatlines

Comment: I doubt you'd need to compile GDAL and the command you'd need is dead simple.

Comment: OK, can you please post the command? I'm sorry but I can't find it anywhere. There are plenty of references on various forums to using GDAL to do the conversion but no one posts how to actually do it.

Comment: I followed the instructions here and it seems to work, I just need to figure out how to crop out the collar area http://nationalmap.gov/ustopo/documents/ustopo2gtif_current.pdf

Answer (score 1):

To convert a GeoPDF image to a GroTIFF with GDAL, use the following command: `gdal_translate input.pdf output.tif`.